# Oracle Cloud MultiPartUpload using PreAuthenticated Request

Tags: java, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I've been searching for hours and I could not find an answer to this: Can you upload files to Oracle Cloud's ObjectStorage using `MultiPartUpload` via a PreAutheticated Request? I know it's possible in just in one go.
I basically need to allow users to upload large files to Object Storage through a Java client and I would like to do it via PAR's. If it is possible, how would that happen? Meaning, do you call the `CreateMultiPartUpload` first and the upload the parts via the PAR? Do you call the `CreateMultiPartUpload` with the PAR?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use multipart uploads with a PAR today, unfortunately. We do hope to make this available very soon, though.

hope you are well!